# How to see the error in controller constructor when using StructureMap?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, structuremap3

I am using StructureMap 3 with MVC 5. The problem is that whenever an exception happens in the controller constructor I get a misleading StructureMap error instead of the actual error.

For example I have the following controller:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    private readonly DataContext db;

    public CustomerService(DataContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;

        // Some code that causes exception
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    }
}
```

Whenever I try to access an action from that controller I get the following StructureMap error:

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
```

What can I do to see the actual exception when there is a problem in a controller constructor?

Comment: How have you setup the StructureMap dependency resolver or container? Should be in `IoC.cs`.

Comment: Yes, it's set up properly and is working fine. The only issue is this misleading error